#  javascript change event fires when page loads - how to avoid this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form with chained select boxes. The zend controller sets the default values for these select boxes (values come from the db). I am a jquery novice.

```
$form->setDefaults($data);
```

a jquery file is loaded :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        // set up the chained select
        $("#region").remoteChained("#country", "/ws/regionstructure");
        $("#province").remoteChained("#region", "/ws/regionstructure");
        $("#town").remoteChained("#province", "/ws/regionstructure");

     });
```

The problem is that when the page loads it is triggering the change event for country and resetting all of the selects.

Here is the remoteChained jquery code that is being called:

```
/*
 * Remote Chained - jQuery AJAX(J) chained selects plugin
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2010-2011 Mika Tuupola
 *
 * Licensed under the MIT license:
 *   http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
 *
 */

(function($) {

    $.fn.remoteChained = function(parent_selector, url, options) { 

        return this.each(function() {

            /* Save this to self because this changes when scope changes. */            
            var self   = this;
            var backup = $(self).clone();

            /* Handles maximum two parents now. */
            $(parent_selector).each(function() {
                $(this).bind("change", function() {

                    /* Build data array from parents values. */
                    var data = {};
                    $(parent_selector).each(function() {
                        var id = $(this).attr("id");
                        var value = $(":selected", this).val();
                        data[id] = value;
                    });

                    $.getJSON(url, data, function(json) {

                        /* Clear the select. */
                        $("option", self).remove();

                        /* Add new options from json. */
                        for (var key in json) {
                            if (!json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            /* This sets the default selected. */
                            if ("selected" == key) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            var option = $("<option />").val(key).append(json[key]);
                            $(self).append(option);    
                        }

                        /* Loop option again to set selected. IE needed this... */ 
                        $(self).children().each(function() {
                            if ($(this).val() == json["selected"]) {
                                $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
                            }
                        });

                        /* If we have only the default value disable select. */
                        if (1 == $("option", self).size() && $(self).val() === "") {
                            $(self).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        } else {
                            $(self).removeAttr("disabled");
                        }

                        /* Force updating the children. */
                        $(self).trigger("change");

                    });
                });

                /* Force updating the children. */
                $(this).trigger("change");             

            });
        });
    };

    /* Alias for those who like to use more English like syntax. */
    $.fn.remoteChainedTo = $.fn.remoteChained;

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Setting the defaults in PHP from a controller shouldn't cause the change event to trigger, because this is all server side.  The webpage doesn't exist yet.  You should probably only call setDefaults if the form hasn't been posted.

Comment: you're right drew - I'll amend my question

Comment: I think the line `$(this).trigger("change");` is running unconditionally when you create register the new chained input.  That is what I think is causing the change even to fire.  That said, I am not sure what the solution is or if it is safe to remove that line, hopefully someone can answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issue with removing the `change` event, but the way that plugin works seems highly inefficient. I refactored this (untested), so give this a go and see how it works for you.

You can call it like so:

```
$( "#region" ).remoteChained( { parentSelector: "#country", url: "/ws/regionstructure" } );
$( "#province" ).remoteChained( { parentSelector: "#region", url: "/ws/regionstructure" } );
$( "#town" ).remoteChained( { parentSelector: "#province", url: "/ws/regionstructure" } );
```

This shouldn't trigger the `change` event. If you find you need to do this, you can do something like this:

```
$( '#region' ).trigger( 'change' );
```

Here is the new plugin code. Let me know if you have any issues with it:

```
( function( $ ) {

    $.fn.remoteChained = function ( options ) {
        var defaults = { },
            settings = $.extend( { }, defaults, options );

        return this.each( function () {

            var el = $( this ),
                parent = $(settings.parentSelector),
                data = { };

            parent.each( function () {
                var el = $(this);
                data[ el.attr( 'id' ) ] = el.find( ':selected' ).val(); 
            });

            parentSelector.bind( 'change.remotechanged', function ( e ) {
                var request = $.ajax( { url: settings.url, data: data } );

                request.done( function ( response ) {
                    var newOption;

                    el.find( 'option' ).remove();

                    for ( var key in response ) {
                        if ( !response.hasOwnProperty( key ) ) {
                            continue;
                        }

                        newOption = $( '<option />' )
                            .val( key )
                            .append( response[ key ] );

                        key === 'selected' && newOption.attr( 'selected', 'selected' );

                        newOption.appendTo( el );
                    }

                    if ( el.find( 'option' ).length === 1 && el.val() === '' ) {
                        el.attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
                    } else {
                        el.removeAttr( 'disabled' );
                    }
                });
            });

        });

    };

})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for that. I haven't been able to get it to work yet. I think there is an error in the lines you gave me to call it : $( "#region" ).remoteChained( { parentSelector: "#country", url: "/ws/regionstructure" } );
$( "#province" ).remoteChained( { parentSelector: "#region", url: "/ws/regionstructure" } );
$( "#town" ).remoteChained( { parentSelector: "#province", url: "/ws/regionstructure" } );  ----- The reason I think this is that my jquery after those lines no longer works (simple hide statement): $("#refreshregionalstructure").hide();

Comment: I meant to say that no ajax request takes place.

Comment: I have accepted this answer as you worked for it thanks. In the end, I ended up using this plugin https://github.com/hornairs/jQuery-Chained-Select which is a more complete solution